# .net API best pratice

Tags: .net

We are planning to write an API layer for our .net Winforms application. I have tried to google around for good examples for some best practises but didn't find much that could answer my questions. We current have the following structure:

Business logic are in separate assemblies based on the business areas. So `ST.Invoice.Business.dll`, `ST.Order.Business.dll` and so on. Then we have `ST.Invoice.Bussiness.DC.dll`, `ST.Order.Business.DC.dll` and so on (DC means data contracts which has all the interfaces). We have the same structure for the Data layer (`ST.Invoice.Data.dll`) These assemblies are loaded through the Service Factory on run time and you can access them by going through `ServiceFactory.InvoiceBusinessService.GetInvoices(...)`. Now we need to exposes functionality to other 3rd party applications. If I were to give them all the functionality of let say invoices, can I just given the above assemblies relating to invoices or do I need to create another assembly say called `ST.Invoice.BusinessAPI.dll` (which would have pretty much the same public methods) which then calls the methods in the `ST.Invoice.Business.dll` to get the work done

I just need a guideline on how to write API and does it mean giving them our dlls to use our BI and talk to our DB

Comment: Just a recommendation for security: don't "blacklist", do "whitelist". Start from scratch in a library and only add the methods you think the API needs. That way you avoid people doing nasty things because they can only do the things you revised and thought about.

Answer (score 0):

[Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)

Combine that with [FxCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/07/26/fxcop-10-0-is-available.aspx) and you've got a great start.